# Return zero entries, if two entries are found

Tags: mysql

I work on a small project, where a user can activate and deactivate an alarm.
It contains several entities, but the ones to focus on are "alarms" and "alarmactivity".
My intentions are that if alarmactivity contains both a "triggered" and "cancelled" event, then they should cancel eachother out.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT alarmid, 
                                                unixtimestamp, 
                                                latitude, 
                                                longitude, 
                                                severity, 
                                                u.userid AS requestuserid, 
                                                u.names AS requestname, 
                                                aa.alarmevent AS alarmevent
                                            FROM alarms AS a
                                            LEFT JOIN users AS u ON userid = useridfk
                                            RIGHT JOIN usersgroups AS ug ON a.groupidfk = ug.groupidfk
                                            RIGHT JOIN alarmactivity AS aa ON a.alarmid = aa.alarmidfk
                                            WHERE unixtimestamp > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-1800)
                                            ORDER BY requestuserid
```

...and returns something like this:
[image]

The result is based on these entities:

**Alarms**

[image]

**Alarmevents**

[image]

In this case, it should return zero rows. Several alarms can be set at once, so if it contains two "triggered"-rows and one "cancelled"-alarm, it should return only the alarm, which has not been cancelled.
I tried different IF-solutions, but since it involves checking several rows at once, I'm a bit stuck.

I tried a PHP-solution as well, but it only returns zero rows, 50% of the time for some reason - so I try to go for a more elegant solution and hope, it takes care of this problem at the same time.

Can you give me a push in the right direction, please?

Edit: just forgot to mention that a cancelled alarm can never be reactivated - so another alarm will generate a new row in "alarms".
Also, the reason I don't just delete the alarm from the entity is that I want to keep track of activated alarms.

Comment: can you please provide your expected output in table format

Comment: If I understand your reply correctly, then the output is really just like the result, shown just below the querystring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `RIGHT JOIN alarmactivity`
 you can

```
select alarmactivity.*
from
(
         select alarmidfk 
         from alarmactivity 
         group by alarmidfk 
         having count(alarmevent)=1
) as oneEvents
inner join 
alarmactivity on alarmactivity.alarmidfk=oneEvents.alarmidfk
```

Comment: It works perfectly - thanks a million. I didn't know about the "having" command